# CSS header navigation UL / LI links ...what am I doing wrong?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, html-lists

I have a header with a logo on the left, more content in the middle and 3 navigation links on the right. The header will be about 50 pixels tall due to the height of the logo, so the navigation links on the right side (UL / LI) should also stretch the full height.

So if someone hovers the LI, he can click the link and also if someone hovers over the link, the border-top should change colors.

Right now, for some reason, both are not working :( Neither does the #FF0000 border change colors and neither does the LI link stretch the full height of the header.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? :(

I think it might have something to do with bootstrap but I'm not sure where.

Here is a fiddle just in case:
http://jsfiddle.net/QLQ7d/

```
<header class="header_global">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-5 vs"><img src="logo.jpg" class="logoimg" width="180" height="50"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-7 vs">More Content</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 vs">

    <nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>      
    <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>      
    </ul>
    </nav>

    </div>      

</div>
</div>
</header>
```

And this CSS:

```
.header_global nav {
position: relative;
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border: 0 none;
float: right;
margin-top: 0;
text-align: center;
display: block;
}
nav ul {
list-style: none outside none;
margin: 0;
}
.header_global{
border-bottom:1px solid #ececec;
}
.header_global nav li {
display: inline-block;
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 0;
width: auto;
}
.header_global nav a, .header-global li a {
  border-top: 22px solid #FFFFFF !important;
font-size: 14px;
padding: 25px;   
}
.header_global nav a:hover {
  border-top: 22px solid #FF0000 !important;
font-size: 14px;
padding: 25px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a few adjustments to your code. Also, your column structure which should "add" to 12 cols.

http://jsfiddle.net/QLQ7d/3/

**CSS**

```
.header_global nav {
    position: relative;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 0 none;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
}
.header_global{
    border-bottom:1px solid #ececec;
}
.header_global nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.header_global nav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 25px; 
    border-top: 22px solid #FFFFFF !important;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.header_global nav li a:hover {
    border-top: 22px solid #FF0000 !important;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<header class="header_global">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-4 vs"><img src="logo.jpg" class="logoimg" width="180" height="50"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 vs">More Content</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 vs">

    <nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>      
    <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>      
    </ul>
    </nav>

    </div>      

</div>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: Works perfectly and now I see what I did wrong. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do but check out this [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QLQ7d/5/), I removed some unnecessary code and gave your nav a height of 50px.
BTW You should never use `!important` just like that, if you don't know what's wrong.

Here goes:

```
.header_global nav {
    position: absolute;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 0 none;
    top:-50px;
    right:0;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ececec;
    height:50px;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
}
.header_global nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    height:100%;
}
.header_global nav li a {
    height:50px;
}
.header_global nav a:hover {
    border-top: 22px solid #FF0000;
}
```